# How can I include the HTTP request body when redirecting requests with CloudFront functions?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to add a behavior to my CloudFront distribution to redirect requests to `my.domain/api` to `api.my.domain`. I've tried a regular /api behavior but I was getting 403 errors from API Gateway, so a Reddit user suggested I try CloudFront functions.

I was able to set up a CloudFront function to do the redirect, but it seems to be dropping the HTTP request body from my POST requests.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var headers = request.headers;
    var host = request.headers.host.value;
    var uri = request.uri;
    
    var newURL = 'https://api.my.domain' + uri;
    var response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: { 
            "location": { "value": newURL }
        }
    };
    return response;
}
```

Is it possible to do this with CloudFront functions? Or do I need to use Lambda@Edge instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out - 302 redirects cause the client to reissue a GET request to the new domain without an HTTP body, even if the original request was a POST. The solution was to use a 307 redirect instead which forces the client to reissue the exact same request to the new host. Once I changed the 302 to a 307 everything worked as expected.